# Multiple Linear Regression from scratch in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm fairly new to machine learning. I'm teaching myself how to implement Multiple Linear Regression from scratch in Python. This isn't a homework problem, just a personal initiative.

I'm using the [Boston Housing dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~delve/data/boston/bostonDetail.html) for this. The coefficient values and intercept don't match scikit-learn's values. Can someone please help identify what I'm doing wrong and possibly provide the solution as well? I'd like to learn from it. I've been at it for a week now.

[Here](https://repl.it/repls/ConsiderableQuarrelsomePublisher) is the code for Multiple Linear Regression from scratch:

[Here](https://repl.it/repls/AccomplishedBaggyTechnology) is the code for Multiple Linear Regression using sklearn:

#### Coefficients in sklearn - `[ 7.72409427 -0.01673352]`

#### Intercept in sklearn - `-19.129291077739456`

Features I'm using - `RM` and `CRIM`
Dependent variable - house prices

equations for gradient descent I'm using (I think these might be incorrect):

#### For intercept

`-(2 / N) * SUM OF y_val - (m1x1 + m2x2 + b)`
for all values of x and y

#### For m1

`-(2/N) * SUM OF x1 * (y_val - (m1x1 + m2x2 + b))`
for all values of x and y

#### For m2

`-(2/N) * SUM OF x2 * (y_val - (m1x1 + m2x2 + b))`
for all values of x and y

Comment: Hi, 3 things. 1. LinearRegression in sklearn uses OLS not gradient descent by default, your implementation used gradient descent (minor but just a heads up). 2. This is probably a better fit for [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) . 3. Even they will ask you to do a little more digging and pin point the divergence

Comment: Hi Srini, I didn't know sklearn uses OLS, thanks for clarifying that. I'll post the question on Cross-Validated in a bit. and I've added the equations I'm using. I think I may be wrong there.

Comment: Is this question active? The answer was not accepted, no feedback.